# Generate native oracle database alphanumeric sequence

Tags: database, database-design, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

Can anyone give me some idea to generate native oracle database alphanumeric sequence with column length 4, like 000A,000B and so on. I need 200k or more records of this sequence.

Any ideas/solutions are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `SELECT` statement to generate hexadecimal values then:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(LEVEL, 'FM0000X')
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 200000;
```

If you want a `SEQUENCE` then they only generate numeric values; however, you can wrap its output in the same `TO_CHAR` function:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE table_name__id__seq;

CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id VARCHAR2(5)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (id)
VALUES (TO_CHAR(table_name__id__seq.NEXTVAL, 'FM0000X'));

SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | ID |
> | --- |
> | 00001 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a0aa660ee84c32f77850bf656a277d7a)*